# G-SHEET Formula to show 800 or Greater number

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet, gsheets

So here is what i have so far ( **=multiply(D138,F138)-G138+E138-H138**) Now what I would like to do is either show 800 if that formula is less or show the greater number.

I know I had a similar set up in the past but I had to change my formula a bit and lost it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `max()`, like this:

```
=max(800, D138 * F138 - G138 + E138 - H138)
```

See [max()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094013).

Answer (score 0):

MAX formula would be the best way, that would also work:

```
=IF(multiply(D138,F138)-G138+E138-H138)>800,multiply(D138,F138)-G138+E138-H138),800)
```